# why it didn't go through the thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was checking if the sign Up button is clicked it do something in another thread but it didn't go to the end of thread ?

```
    if(!(email.isEmpty() ||username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty())){
     Main.users.add(new User(username, password, email));
                        new Thread(new SocketSender(Main.socket, Main.users)).start();
   Thread.sleep(1000);
   System.out.println("here");
   new Thread(new ServerReciver(Main.socket)).start();
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   System.out.println("here");
   Main.pstage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/logIn.fxml")),700,700))}
```

**Socket Sender**

```
public class SocketSender  implements  Runnable{
    Socket socket;
    Object object;

    public SocketSender(Socket socket, Object object) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.object = object;
    }

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream write = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        write.writeObject(object);
        write.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

**Server Reciver**

```
public class ServerReciver implements  Runnable {
    Socket socket;

    public ServerReciver(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("log1");
        try {
            System.out.println("log2");
            ObjectInputStream read = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("log3");
            Object o = read.readObject();
            System.out.println("ma");
            if(o instanceof User){
                System.out.println(log4);
                Server.getUsers().add((User) o);
            }
            else if(o instanceof Artist){
                Server.getArtists().add((Artist) o);
            }
            else if(o instanceof PlayList){
                Server.getPlayLists().add((PlayList) o);
            }
            else if(o instanceof Song){
                Server.getSongs().add((Song) o);
            }
            else if(o instanceof Album){
                Server.getAlbums().add((Album) o);
            }
            System.out.println(log6);
            Server.write();
            System.out.println(log7);
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.println(Server.getUsers().get(0));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

in the Server receiver it prints the 2 first log but it didn't print all the logs!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simply: you can't use the **same** socket object to send and read data at the same time.

What you are trying is like: using your own mobile phone to call your own number and then talk to you (in a way that works).

In other words: instead of reusing some `Main.socket` you simply have to create two distinct sockets in the first place.

But of course, there is **zero** point in doing things in *this* order. Don't build a JavaFX application and then try to add in client/server connectivity to a remote system.

Start by learning how to do that client/server thing, for example by reading the corresponding Oracle [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/). And then, when you have written small command line tools that nicely communicate via sockets; even to a remote system; then take that knowledge forward and build it into your JavaFX application. Instead of trying to learn juggling while learning to use the unicycle.

Answer (score 0):

To create server's client use `java.net.Socket`:

```
Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 9090);
        BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String answer = input.readLine();
```

To create server use `java.net.ServerSocket` :

```
ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9090);

        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();

                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println(new Date().toString());
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
```

Comment: it doesn't work actually my program needs to add object in arrays then write the arrays in file it will do it by server and clients need to read file to get any information do you any other suggestion?

Comment: after lot's of debug i understand that that my program doesn't run the run part of the threads and all of my classes are ok now could you please help me?!